# Image is not showing when I try to fetch image from Folder (Folder is on web server)

Tags: asp.net

Please check this URL http://pehravnifashion.com/Best-Sherwani.aspx . Everything is okay but Image is not showing to my web page.

My code

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath", "admin/FESTIVALWEAR\\") %>' PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("id", "ProductDetails.aspx?id={0}") %>' />
```

Please Help me..

Answer (score 1):

The image source you are setting is not right. when I inspected the generated html of your page, the image source is showing up as **"admin/FESTIVALWEAR\"**. You will have to correct it with proper image source. setting it up as `ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath", "admin/FESTIVALWEAR\\") %>'` is not correct.

Comment: @PankilAgrawal, can you first debug your application and see what is coming at "ImageUrl" ?. As I mentioned, please look through your generated html code, and you will see the ImageUrl is not a valid url to an image. thats why the image is not showing up. I cannot infet what you are trying to show by Eval("ImagePath", "admin/FESTIVALWEAR\\"). You will have to show more code or what you are trying to get in the image url string.

Comment: solved. check this link http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/719153/Image-is-not-showing-while-I-am-fetching-image-fro#NewEntryGroup